# ActiveScaffold search date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activescaffold

I am developing a Rails application using ActiveScaffold.

The thing is that I need to filter a list of results by a date range.

(SQL equivalent 'BETWEEN ? AND ?')

I know that ActiveScaffold has a feature that already does that, but it has too many options. 
(Past, Future, Range, =, ...., Between). In this case, I only need the Between option in that combo.

I tried overriding the field using the Helper, but the closest I got was to display 3 different combos (one for year, one for month, one for day).

Is there any way to override Active Scaffold so that only displays the "Between" option?

**EDIT**
Active Scaffold already does the search part well. 
I am trying to change the visual part so it doesn't display so many options.

**EDIT 2**
The calendar plugins for rails are dated from 2009 or they aren't under maintenance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a range as a parameter in AR.

```
Model.where(:date => from..to)
```

Also, I'm not sure if ActiveScaffold has something to do with it. Normally, all the tasks like this one can be perfectly solved within plain ActiveRecord.

EDIT: 
As it turns out, author also needs to get the user's input for the boundaries.
This is a common task that can be solved with one of the thouhands js plugins for datepickers.
I would recommend you not to stick to ActiveScaffold for that purpose.
Try this simple [Jquery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), and it will turn normal text field into that drop-down calendar. You will only need several lines of javascript then.
If you need further advise, just ask.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately my problem is a visual problem.
ActiveScaffold actually does the filtering well, but how it displays it is my problem. Ideally I would need to display two datepickers.

Comment: Ok, then we face two dedicated tasks here: one for actually _selecting_ the records, and another one for getting user input. My answer addresses the first one only.
I'll update the answer now.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the jQuery datepicker, it was just what I needed for the text fields. Marking your answer as the correct.